# CSS Scroll Snapping to full height sections for only part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**I'm trying to get full height snapping to work, but only for certain sections of the page.**

I'm using a data attribute on each section and Jquery to set a parent element with snapping true or false depending on if the section inside the viewport.

The Jquery works fine until I add the CSS, which depending on which parent element I target does one of the following 3 things:

- Doesn't snap, even though the rules are applied.
- Snaps, but skips to the bottom/top of the page
- locks the page scroll preventing it from scrolling the first snapping
  point into view.

I was basing it off of the folloing codepens:

- https://codepen.io/Chokcoco/pen/YzPPvBV
- https://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/MJgQqR

I'm thinking having the non-snapping section inside of the snap parent is the main issue, but the PHP template has no easy way to wrap the snapping sections individually without a lot of hassle, hoping it's something that will be easier to solve via another method.

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom < viewportBottom;
};
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  $('section').each(function() {
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      $('main').attr('data-snap', $(this).attr('data-snap'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
section[data-snap="false"] {
  height: 200vh;
}

main[data-snap="true"]>div.articles {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto !important;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

main>div.articles>section[data-snap="true"] {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #888;
}

section,
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bg1 {
  background: #f6da78
}

.bg2 {
  background: #ffaa98
}

.bg3 {
  background: #00da78
}

.bg4 {
  background: #f60f78
}

.bg5 {
  background: #f6ffaa
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="articles">
    <section data-snap="false" class="bg1">
      <h2>Section 1 False</h2>
    </section>
    <section data-snap="true" class="bg2">
      <h2>Section 2 True</h2>
    </section>
    <section data-snap="true" class="bg3">
      <h2>Section 3 True</h2>
    </section>
    <section data-snap="true" class="bg4">
      <h2>Section 4 True</h2>
    </section>
    <section data-snap="true" class="bg5">
      <h2>Section 5 True</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <h2>SOME FOOTER AREA</h2>
</footer>
```